# removing elements from a list defined by another list

Tags: python

How would I remove elements in a list in this form

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]

c = b + a     # [6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5]

# c = c - b    expected output: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Any other example which can let me understand the question better?

Comment: @thefourtheye He wants to take the set difference, ie c = c-b = a\b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [6,7,8,9,10]
>>> c = b + a
>>> c
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = set(b)
>>> c = [x for x in c if x not in b]
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

If you want a reference on `set`, look [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#func-set).

Comment: if `b` is sufficiently large, you should put it into a `set` first, since this is O(n*m)

Comment: your comment is somewhat misleading; set lookups aren't fast because they're de-duped, they're fast because they're O(1) hash lookups

Comment: @roippi - I was trying to put it in simple terms for the OP, who seems to be a newbie.  But, I guess it _is_ technically incorrect/misleading.  I'll add a link instead.

Answer (score 3):

Using `b` as a set which helps you in faster lookups, if the length of `b` is very big

```
a, b = [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]
c, b = a + b, set(b)
c = filter(lambda x: x not in b, c)
print c
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```